# Sed command to process the input stream and replace all HTML <i> tags by <em> tags

Tags: html, bash, sed

i'm tring to write a regex with sed command to process the input stream and replace all HTML  tags by  tags so that for example:

```
This is <i id="x">emphasized text</i> and <i>so is this</i>.
```

will be replaced by

```
This is <em id="x">emphasized text</em> and <em>so is this</em>.
```

I tried the following :

```
sed -r 's/<\/?i[^>]*> / <\/?em[^>]*>/ /g'
```

can somone advise how to write it ?

Comment: May be: `sed -e 's/<i/<em/g' -e 's/i>/em>/g'`. I will suggest you to use appropriate parser for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a more appropriate tool ; HTML isn't a regular language and as such [shouldn't be parsed with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1678362), and `sed` is a line-based tool while linefeeds are ignored in HTML.

If you are sure you can ignore that (your HTML is the most standard there is, you won't ever have a tag whose definition is spread on multiple lines, etc.), the following GNU `sed` command might work for you :

```
sed -E 's@<(/?)i\b@<\1em@g'
```

We use `-E`RE regex rather than the default BRE flavour in order to be able to use the `\b` "word-boundary" meta-character that will make sure the i isn't followed by other letters (don't want to match `<img`, `<input` or `<iframe` tags) ; use `-r` for older GNU `sed` versions.

We get to replace `</i` and `<i` in a single pass by capturing the optional `/` into a capturing group which we refer to in the replacement pattern. While matching `<i` the replacement will be `<em` since the capturing group is empty, while matching `</i` it will be `</em`.

I used `@` as a separator for the search/replace command instead of the usual `/` in order to avoid having to escape `/` in the pattern.

Otherwise you should look into HTML or even XML parsers if you're parsing XHTML.

Comment: Hu, `sed` has no `-P` flag, I was confusing it with `grep`. I'll see what I can do

Comment: @MottiCohen if you're using GNU sed, it's ERE regex flavour also supports `\b` : https://ideone.com/qJYr5r

Comment: its working on GNU sed but i dont use GNU sed. i need it to work with the:       sed -r 's/______ / ______/g'

Comment: @MottiCohen hmm, the edit to your comment makes me doubt you're using something else than GNU sed, the `-r` flag is pretty much specific to GNU sed AFAIK. Can you try `sed -r 's@<(/?)i\b@<\1em@g'` ? Or if you prefer, `sed -r 's/<(\/?)i\b/<\1em/g'` ? (those are the same, I just use `@` as a separator in the first one to avoid having to escape the `/` in the pattern)

Comment: Its working thank you very very much. i will be happy to get explanation on the syntex

Comment: I'm guessing you're using an older GNU sed version where `-E` wasn't implemented, that change is somewhat recent. I've edited my answer with a bit more information, please tell me if you're still unclear on some points :)